# using locking method to serialize transaction

Tags: database, transactions

I am a newer in database ,i read an article about transaction .

We have two kind of Schedule:Serial and Concurrency.

My question is :
Suppose i have a schedule that is non-serializable .

Does sql use a kind of locking method for that to serialize that?Like 2pl and etc?

Answer (score 0):

Without stating which database system you're using this question is not answerable (even if I understand it correctly). Each database system - Oracle, Sql server, MySql, etc - is a separate implementation with their own internal ways of doing things.

Look up optimistic and pessimistic locking in articles about the database of your choice as a way to get started if you're a developer, or get a book on DBMS design if you're a computer science student.